# data url image save as png

Tags: php, image, base64

Lets say I have this data url from Apple:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6%2BR8AAAAlElEQVR42oWQQRHEIAxF10ElVAISVgo3bCABCUhYCZWAhEpAQpoD6bzJhNnDO0DyyA8fEXkppXyVCpLViDUfyqVIQN9JFMY637hrlCySFauL21E7KVWbAIGx56rnSLqc5KPXSLo3kySalPhTygFhRDtFC09EIsMeZJSGBj7Qveh3OJW89syImiH%2BIO2BOJX0XwA2%2BQEL4pAhSX4aBQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D
```

That I want to save as a png file.How do I do That?
Rightclicking and 'Save image as' is not working(Why?)
So I thought I should use a PHP script with the 'base64_decode' function:

```
    $img = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA9QAAAAkCAMAAABfcIIyAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAHVQTFRFAAAA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F5YtmQAAAACd0Uk5TAAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODxAREhMUFRYXGBkaGxwdHh8gISIjJCUmZiD6WAAAAdlJREFUeF7t3btuFEEQheFzunotGYkIERA4spn3fyeHiAgEEtsXB82s2eEJavR%2F0Wjyo75XWfHpw4MkSXNqCkA2lr2%2B%2Fvz63n15qpI0x5yTSAM52XaxJLVXf%2FkoaY6xQk2sgXy8Ql2KJf3wS5HG6HMMQg3kZNkuxVGKNLxJo48%2BxhxTpBrIx7JcXEqUKJI3zd77CjWLaiAle4U6Iixv6q33MfocTL%2BBlCy7OEqJqCFvs%2FV2m3%2BTaiAd6zb7rlHtrbc1VA%2Bm30BSa%2B%2B7RNSo4a21thbVTL%2BBnCy7rCV1rdXbtbXW%2B%2Bh%2Ft78BZLM2v6NE1Fov%2FrpC3Zl%2BA2l5H6lrrRe%2FXNu%2BqCbUQE57qGvsoW5t9D4H028gJculOKLUWuvFz%2B16O9NipAZSsm8nWpfq53ZlTQ3k9s%2BamlADZ0CogZMh1MDJEGrgZAg1cDL%2Fh5ojLSC1%2ByMtLp8A2R0un3BNFEjv%2FpooDzqA9O4fdPD0Esju8PSSIglAdsciCZQzArI7lDOat30yCg8CGe2FB1eovZcI7oMSwUBSq0TwWlQHxfyBEzgW86ftDpDase0ODfKA7A4N8mhlC2R318r2px%2BeQqLpPJDae9P5%2FmrVz491%2FWekBlKy7PXVfn9rb9xXsMD2wdOcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

header("Content-type: image/png");
echo base64_decode($img);
```

That is giving me back the broken image icon :

[image]

How should I solve this problem and save a data url image to a file?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, but your base64 is urlencoded. I urldecoded it for you: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAANCAYAAABy6+R8AAAAlElEQVR42oWQQRHEIAxF10ElVAISVgo3bCABCUhYCZWAhEpAQpoD6bzJhNnDO0DyyA8fEXkppXyVCpLViDUfyqVIQN9JFMY637hrlCySFauL21E7KVWbAIGx56rnSLqc5KPXSLo3kySalPhTygFhRDtFC09EIsMeZJSGBj7Qveh3OJW89syImiH+IO2BOJX0XwA2+QEL4pAhSX4aBQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

or do it yourself:
`base64_decode(urldecode($img));`

Comment: It works fine now -- you can paste it [somewhere like here](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to test.